# Why are the spaces between these p elements when margin and padding are zero?

Tags: html, css

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr5s3jp5/). The HTML, simplified, is basically this

```
<div id="canvas">
   <p><span></span><span></span></p>
   <p><span></span><span></span></p>
</div>
```

With this CSS

```
#canvas p
{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#canvas p span
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: thin solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

It renders like this:

[image]

Why are there spaces between the rows? DOM Inspector tells me the spans have zero margin and padding as well as the p tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `span`'s. Default is `baseline`

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mr5s3jp5/1/)

```css
#canvas p {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#canvas p span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: thin solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <p><span id="p-1_1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span><span id="p0_1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span><span id="p1_1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span>
  </p>
  <p><span id="p-1_0" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span><span id="p0_0" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span><span id="p1_0" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span>
  </p>
  <p><span id="p-1_-1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span><span id="p0_-1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span><span id="p1_-1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: **baseline** - `Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent` **top** `Align the top of the element and its descendants with the top of the entire line.`. You could change it to `middle` or `bottom` and it would still work https://jsfiddle.net/mr5s3jp5/4/

Comment: I understand what baseline does, but what does that have to do with the gap?

Comment: That white space is for the descenders http://jsfiddle.net/BZeLR/106/, and there is few options to fix that, one is to change `vertical-align` and then this happens http://jsfiddle.net/BZeLR/107/